# Identifying CAAnimation in animationDidStop callback failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, animation

How to identify CAAnimation after completion? I tried KVO by setting a string value as animationID and checking it in animationDidStop method. But KVO returns an `integer` sometimes instead of a `string` animationID and the app is crashing.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animationID:(NSString*)animationid
{
    // Prepare the animation from the current position to the new position
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
    [animation setDuration:duration];

    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    animation.delegate=self;
    [animation setValue:animationid forKey:@"animationID"];
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    // Update the layer's position so that the layer doesn't snap back when the animation completes.
    layer.position = point;

    // Add the animation, overriding the implicit animation.
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

and callback is:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {

    id animationIDString=[animation valueForKey:@"animationID"];
    // this is coming as an int value sometimes and the code below this fails ..
    if([animationIDString isEqual:@"animation1"]) {
        //animation is animation1
        _movieBalloonImageView.hidden=NO;
        _storiesBalloonImageView.hidden=NO;
        _rhymesBalloonImageView.hidden=NO;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
}
}
```

What can be the possible reason? Is it because the animation gets destroyed before this delegate gets called?
I am setting `removedOnCompletion` to NO and `fillmode` to `kCAFillModeForwards`.But the code is not working as expected.

```
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Or is there any alternative method to do this? I am calling the `moveLayer` method in several places in the viewController.